# Bootstrap button checkbox not working with javascript handling checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following for testing purposes:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $readyHomeRow['HomeID']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $readyHomeRow['HomeID']; ?>"></td>
<td><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $readyHomeRow['HomeID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $readyHomeRow['HomeID']; ?>"> Assign Order</label></div></td>
```

The first one will interact correctly with the dispatchCheckBox.php file but the second one doesn't. I can't seem to figure out what needs to be changed within my script tags to interact correctly.

Javascript:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    if(checked){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.post('functions/dispatchCheckBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
            // data = 0 - means that there was an error
            // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
            if(data == 1){
                // Do something or do nothing :-)
                //alert('Data was saved in db!');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.post('functions/dispatchUnCheckBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
            // data = 0 - means that there was an error
            // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
            if(data == 1){
                // Do something or do nothing :-)
                //alert('Data was saved in db!');
            }
        });
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So is your second checkbox not triggering the `click` event or is it not interacting correctly with your php file? If it's the later perhaps you should include your php code where it's not working properly

Comment: Its not interacting with the click event. The php works fine

Comment: @JohnLang, did you end up finding a solution for this? [I have the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945761/onclick-for-bootstrap-btn-group-checkbox-works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-browser), looking at the CSS for the checkbox, I think it might have to do with the way it is styled but not sure which styles are causing it.