# onclick for Bootstrap .btn-group checkbox works in JSFiddle but not browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The form below contains a Bootstrap toggle button group that uses checkboxes. **I need to listen for click events on the checkbox inputs.**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example: Bootstrap toggle button group</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <form role="form" id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label for="fname">Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="fname" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          a
          <input type="checkbox" value="a" name="fname">
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          b
          <input type="checkbox" value="b" name="fname">
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          c
          <input type="checkbox" value="c" name="fname">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
   
 $('#fname input').click(function() {
          console.log('you clicked '+$(this).attr('value'))
          });

});
//]]></script>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

For the purpose of this example, I have registered the following handler that prints the value of a checkbox when clicked:

```
$(function() {
    
  $('#fname input').click(function() {
    console.log('you clicked '+$(this).attr('value'))
  });

});
```

This works fine in ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/fs9x3bc8/1/)) - when you select an option in the button group, the handler prints the value of the underlying checkbox to the console as expected.

**But when I run the page in my browser and make a selection, the handler does not fire, i.e. nothing is printed to the console. Why is this?** I have copied the document exactly as it appears in the JSFiddle iframe and have also tried running it on both Chrome (v85) and Firefox (v78.0.2) to no avail.

**Note:** There is a 404 error for the `result-light.css` stylesheet that results when the page initially loads in the browser but it looks to be just a Fiddle stylesheet and removing it doesn't have any effect.

Also, I need to listen for click events specifically so `on('change'` will not help.

**Note:** I noticed that Bootstrap styles the checkbox inputs with property `pointer-events: none;`, could this be what's causing the click handler to be unresponsive in the browser? Setting it to `initial` or `inherit` does not seem to have an effect.

---

**EDIT:** I've voted to close this question as the problem was a mistake on my part. At the time of posting, I hadn't realised that the script I was running in my browser used Bootstrap 3.4.1 whereas the JSFiddle used a newer version 4.4.1.

I could be wrong, but I think the reason why the `click` handler didn't fire in the browser script was due to the `Button data-API` section of Boostrap 3.4.1's [source code](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js):

```
// BUTTON DATA-API
// ===============

if (!($(e.target).is('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]'))) {
  // Prevent double click on radios, and the double selections (so cancellation) on checkboxes
  e.preventDefault()
  // The target component still receive the focus
  if ($btn.is('input,button')) $btn.trigger('focus')
  else $btn.find('input:visible,button:visible').first().trigger('focus')
}
```

This section prevents double clicks on radios, and double selections on checkboxes and was left out of v4.4.1. Manually omitting it from the v3.4.1's source makes the `click` handler responsive as expected.

If I had to use v3.4.1 as is, I could swap the `click` for `focus` as the radios and checkboxes still receive focus. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/8ro3s7Lz/1/).

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that can replicate the problem outside jsFiddle. If you only copied the contents of the `iframe`'s `body`, for instance, you don't have jQuery loaded and so the jQuery code won't work. (You should be seeing an error.) If I copy the entirety of `body`, then go to `head` and copy all the `script` and `link` elements (except the jsFiddle cruft) into `head` in my new document, and remove the two jsfiddle scripts in `body` (???), it works fine locally. https://pastebin.com/rWRUAgU7

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you so much for getting back. I was copying the contents of the JSFiddle iframe in its entirety and wasn't sure which scripts to leave out so didn't include the `head` tag in my post for the sake of brevity. I'm also working in R and hadn't realised that the dependencies that it loads were interfering with mine. When I run your pastebin code, it works exactly as expected.

Comment: It has also helped me isolate the issue (I think). R is using an older version of Bootstrap (3.4.1), I have amended the code in my post to reflect this - could you please confirm if the error is reproducible now?

Comment: The updated code in the question has syntax errors in the JavaScript: Those backslashes in front of the single quotes shouldn't be there. If I fix those, clicking the checkboxes doesn't trigger any console.log calls. Removing bootstrap, the calls occur. I hope that helps.

Comment: Oops, I needed those to escape the `'` in R. I've taken them out. I'm still trying to figure out why the calls don't occur when the older version of Bootstrap is used. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've edited my question to include a possible reason as to why the calls didn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why it is working in JSFiddle, however it looks like the checkbox is essentially hiding behind the button. Are you going to be submitting this form, or just doing some jquery to the page based on selection? If it were me and you want to keep the buttons you can do this:

```
<form role="form" id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label for="fname">Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="fname" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle"  data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-value="a">
          a
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-value="b">
          b
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-value="c">
          c
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
        <script>
        $(function() {
    
  $('#fname label').click(function() {
    console.log('you clicked '+$(this).data('value'))
  });

});
        </script>
```

Comment: The form will be validated and the plugin I'm using requires the validation rules to be attached to the input tags so I can't do away with them unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to interpret your question as best as I could. Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wqse25vj/ I hope it helps.

The hardest part of being a programmer is asking questions. "A problem well-stated is a problem half-solved." holds true. If this is not the answer you were looking for, refine your question and be sure to ask again. As a general note: remember to encapsulate your jQuery code in `$(document).ready()` and continue experimenting & learning HTML, CSS and Bootstrap. For example, I noticed your HTML label tag missing a `for` attribute, and a repetition of class names on your divs and input fields (hint: the Bootstrap class is required for the div only.). All the best to you!

Resources I used:

- https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-using-jquery.php
- copy/pasted the inline-checkbox https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: Sorry! I've emboldened my question, hopefully it's clearer now? I've used the shorthand (`$(function() { ... })`) for `$(document).ready()` so that can't be the issue. I had tried setting `for` but it didn't help. I could be wrong, but each label tag in my example contains exactly one input control and therefore it is automatically associated with that input control even though the `for` attribute is absent ([see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)).

Comment: As for the classes, they were assigned as per Bootstrap's examples [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons).